# xCode app hit counter

Tags: php, xcode, webview, counter

I have an ios restaurant app. There are many pages to the app and most of them are webviews that simply pull a json from a php script on my server.
What im trying to do is everytime someone loads the "Menu" per say, that a hit counter marks +1, etc. I currently have a line in my php code that whenever the php file is called to mark +1 in the database to track how many times that function in the app has been run.
My question is, "Is that the best way to do it?" seems cumbersome to write to a db with  php every time a page is loaded. Or is that really the only way to track it?

Comment: If you are doing it with php, yes, that is the best solution, connect to the DB and +1 the current value. You can also save this information on your device sqlite, I think it will be faster and easier to control.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to store the information on the device and then send an request to the server every X amount of hours/days or when the app is sent into the background or quit.

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=asihttprequest&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/&ei=KmNzT7X4DcKo0AWDkuTnDw&usg=AFQjCNFpUZprrMAY9mTk0aGzEzwSG8L9sg&sig2=qkf3tfsSOQlcRbl4VQFSjw) to send the request to the server.